# Spring-cloud-stream-kafka -- Getting frequent "Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a spring boot application, running with 25 instances, have 25 partitions.
It consume the message and do some calculation by getting the data from cache and put the resultant value into database.

But the performance is very poor for that app, even with these many instances, **CPU usages are very high.**
Max time taken per transaction is 6-8s, average time --> 700ms

In Splunk, IN A MINUTE, I see this `message: [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=TEST] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing thread_name: kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | CG.LOGICALINVENTORY-TEST` around 200 times.

My question is, Why do I get this message frequently??
and can this(getting frequent rebalance) cause the poor performance.

Any thoughts??

Comment: Yes, frequent rebalances cause poor performance. Ideally, Kafka Connect is used to write to databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase `max.poll.interval` and/or decrease `max.poll.records` (Kafka consumer properties).

Comment: I am not getting attempt to heartbeat failed message but it doesn't really increase the performance.

Comment: You might be able to improve performance by increasing `concurrency` (as long a the topic has enough partitions). However, with such high CPU utilization and processing time, you probably need to profile your application to determine where the bottlenecks are.